# No response to touch from XNA page after navigated from Silverlight page

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7, silverlight

I am creating XNA/Silverlight game in Windows Phone Mango. Testing with the emulator in both the Release and Debug mode.

From the main page, I call a settings page written in Silverlight. Then I back out without making any changes. I enter the XNA page, the touch does not work properly.

If I start the app, then enter the XNA page straight from the main page, the touch does work.

In `OnNavigatedTo`:

```
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap
```

Calling the settings page from main page:

```
NavigationService.Navigate( new Uri("/Pages/SettingPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Games.cs buttons tap detection (only the detection lines):

```
while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable && ! actionFound)
{
    GestureSample gestureSample = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
    if (gestureSample.GestureType == GestureType.Tap)
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

I add breakpoints in the 'do work' sections, it only gets hit after 3-4 taps.

I change the settings page to embedded Silverlight on XNA page, the same problem happens.

Just to make sure the timer is working, I change one of the sprites to move up and down in `OnDraw`. The sprite moves OK in both cases.

I been stuck on this for two days, and I got three more pages to code I need to call for a proper game.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: same here. did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Really hard to tell given the information you've shared, but I would check to make sure that you don't have a Silverlight control sitting on top of your game eating the input events. If you have any controls in the game's XAML try setting IsHitTestVisible to false. Likewise try doing the same for controls in Settings.xaml.

Some other thoughts:

- How are you "backing out" from Settings.xaml?
- What happens if you only set Gestures once? i.e. not every time you navigate to the page.
- Have you tried checking MouseState, does it work? (To enable set Tap gesture enabled then check Mouse.GetState().
- Is it possible the !actionFound condition in your while loop is causing problems?